# Make command that installs laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, command-line

I am developing ecommerce website on laravel 5.5
is there any way to make a command that installs it? Something like `php artisan make:ecommerce`. I checked the documentation and read about generating your own commans but there were examples of only working with the code you have at the moment and I didn't saw how I can install files with the commands

Comment: `php artisan` command is built on `Symfony's console component` you need to go through your tutorials to achieve it. This may help you:

https://codeinphp.github.io/post/creating-your-own-artisan-in-php/

Comment: install the laravel app, is copy files to the specific folder. You can make it a command, or you can just write a bash file to copy the files.

Comment: you can make library and publish it on packgist.org and you can pull package via composer